Heroku : ruby app, issue when i tried to push it
i create an app on ruby on rails with heroku
this app already exist online
now I try to push a new version of this one on heroku, but i have an issue.
i already update my ruby and rails version (because this one was an old one an not supported by heroku anymore)
now i have this kind of issue
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.7.8
remote:        Purging Cache. Changing stack from heroku-18 to heroku-20
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.4.22
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git
remote:        ffi-1.17.0-x86_64-linux requires rubygems version >= 3.3.22, which is
remote:        incompatible with the current version, 3.1.6
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git
remote:        ffi-1.17.0-x86_64-linux requires rubygems version >= 3.3.22, which is
remote:        incompatible with the current version, 3.1.6
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
........
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to APP.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/MYAPP.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/MYAPP.git'

RubyGems Environment:

RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.22

RUBY VERSION: 2.7.8 (2023-03-30 patchlevel 225) [x86_64-darwin21]

RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

ruby

x86_64-darwin-21

x86_64-linux




i already try to delete my gemfile and gemfile.lock and run a,
npm install
and also add this conf in the PLATFORM
bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux --add-platform ruby 
but i still have the same issue
any ideas ?
can push the code on heroku

Did you consider upgrading to an up-to-date Ruby version? The version you are using is not supported by Heroku anymore.

You can lock to a previous version.
gem "ffi", "< 1.17.0"
